# How to get a simple field with grouped by field?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, group-by

I'm using Oracle 11G.

I've got the following table in the database:
[image]

I'd like to get the field "Value" for each most recent Id_Number.
For example, from the table above, I'd like to get the rows:

24/08 1 8

03/09 2 95

I managed to get the date and Id_Number for each most recent Id_Number using:

```
select max(Date), Id_Number from table group by Id_Number
```

But I don't see how I can get "Value". Can you guide me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I consider a standard SQL solution:

```
SELECT * FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
 (SELECT * FROM table WHERE t.id_number = id_number AND date > t.date)
```

You can look for questions with "First/Last record within a group" in title and you will find plenty other options.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select t1.*
  from YOUR_TABLE t1
     , (
        select min(date) dat
             , id_number 
          from YOUR_TABLE 
         group by id_number
       ) t2
 where t1.date = t2.dat
   and t1.id_number = t2.id_number
```